# how to secure default plist files in ios app

Tags: ios, security, plist, info-plist

plist files are vulnerable and can easily be accessed by hackers. So I use another methods for saving sensitive data of my app. However there are default plist files like info.plist that are still be accessed. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about plist data, I assume it's just text that you want to secure.
My suggestion is to create them into constants inside an m file.

Your .h file should be something like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
extern NSString *const kTopSecretAppValue;
```

And your .m should be

```
#import "---.h" // this is your file name
NSString *const kTopSecretAppValue = @"Nuclear Launch Codes";
```

Comment: But I want to know how to secure plist files that are default. I think i cannot make info.plist file into hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that you don’t want people to see and if this data is not modified often, you should create a constant on a file that will be **compiled**, because the compiler kind of hide the data you put in it by converting  everything to binary files

Comment: That advice cannot be applied to Info.plist.